# Would a dns name not existing for an IP cause this python error message?

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, suds

I am attempting to run the following script using the suds library:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
import os

t = HttpAuthenticated(username='xxxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxx')
url = 'http://10.14.9.42/NodeBeanService/NodeBean?wsdl'
client = Client(url, transport=t)

filterlimit = client.factory.create('ns3:constraint')
filterlimit.name = "maxObjects"
filterlimit.value = "30000"

filter1 = client.factory.create('ns3:condition')
filter1.name = "status"
filter1.operator = "EQ"
filter1.value = "NORMAL"

filter2 = client.factory.create('ns3:condition')
filter2.name = "notes"
filter2.operator = "NE"
filter2.value = "none"

filter = client.factory.create('ns3:expression')
filter.operator = "AND"
filter.subFilters = [filter1, filter2, filterlimit]

allNodes = client.service.getNodes(filter)
print "Nodes in topology:", len(allNodes.item)

for i in allNodes.item[:]:
  print i.name,i.notes,i.id
```

This script works perfectly fine with one server but when I try another server that does not have a dns name assigned to it I keep getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\pzsr7z.000\Documents>python testnnm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testnnm.py", line 27, in <module>
    allNodes = client.service.getNodes(filter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 521, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 581, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 613, in send
    reply = self.options.transport.send(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 239, in send
    return HttpTransport.send(self, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 82, in send
    fp = self.u2open(u2request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 132, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

What could be causing this error?

EDIT:
Also this script is being run from a windows 7 environment

Comment: Can you access http://10.14.9.42 by other means?

Comment: @Mirac7 actually I just manually added the server to my PC's hosts file using its hostname (not in our DNS servers but it is configured on the server itself) and that caused the error to go away :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get things working correctly by adding the server's IP to my hosts file and then associating it with the hostname that is hardcoded on the server